# How to remove empty rows from table in jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a table in a jasper report.I want to remove empty rows from table which comes because of unchecking of check box "print repeated values"???

Comment: Like i want add next row in the table only when value of first column changes??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is creating the ReportGroup (let's call it **Dedup**, group headers and footers are not required) on the field which that you don't want to show multiple rows for. then on Detail Band set the **PrintWhenExpression**: `$V{Dedup_COUNT} <= 1`. It will show only one row for each value of grouping field you used in **Dedup** group expression.